# Apache SOLR - Searcher options & commits

Tags: solr, lucene

I was reading Solr in Action by manning and had few questions about commits and various searcher warming options .

attribute tells solr to commit documents to be written to disk based on the specified time interval (maxTime), doc Count (maxDocs) .

Question 1 : - Can both maxTime and maxDocs be given together or are these mutually exclusice

The autocommit has a child attibute call openNewSearcher .

The book says openNewSearcher if set to true upon each commit (based on time or count) a new searcher is initialized and warmed .

Question 2: While this happens would all the queries that were issued after the commit was issued get blocked until the searcher is warmed .

Question 3: What would happen to the queries that were in progress and has not finished execution at the moment the commit was issued

Answer (score 0):

Both [maxTime and maxDocs can be set](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig):

> If *either* of these maxDocs or maxTime limits are reached, Solr automatically performs a commit operation. If the autoCommit tag is missing, then only explicit commits will update the index. The decision whether to use auto-commit or not depends on the needs of your application.

In regards to blocking - Solr does not block by default. The new searcher will be available when it's ready. You can use the waitSearcher option an explicit commit to say "hey, I want to wait until I'm sure the new searcher is available before continuing". You shouldn't really have to do this. You can also still send updates to Solr while a commit is taking place.

The previous searcher(s) should close out any active query in progress before being closed.

Comment: Thank you . Concerning question # 2 , does that mean if openNewSearcher is set to true for autocommit , the new searcher is immediately available for servicing new queries eventhough it's not warmed ?  Also the waitSearcher if set to true for an explicit commit , the client queries would block until the new searcher is completely warmed . Kindly correct me if am wrong

Comment: No, waitSearcher would block the client making the request, so that you know when the new searcher is available. As far as I remember, queries are still served while your commit client is waiting. Regarding warming, again, if I remember correctly, the searcher would not be available before warming has taken place, but the old one will still serve content.

Comment: Ok , so that would mean waitSearcher if set to true is just to make commit client aware of the fact (if wait = true) that once commit call returns the new searcher is available and is warmed . The query clients would see stale data until the commit call returns . Kindly confirm . What if waitSearcher = false , the commit call would immediately return (presuming after writing the content to disk) , while the warming happens in the background . In this case would the query clients be serviced by the partially warmed searcher ?